# Can I transfer my PhD to a Masters

Tags: phd, graduate-school, transfer-student

I am pursuing my PhD and am in the first year of my program in Automotive Engineering. I completed my Masters in the same field, at the same school. I am having a tough time with my adviser and go into depression all time. I cannot take it any more. He threatens to take away my funding each day something I cannot afford. I am an international student and if I let go I will have to go back to my country and will be left with nothing. I wanted to know whether I will be able to transfer to a masters program from a PhD program. We have a Mechanical Engg. Dept in our college and the courses are common. They have a no thesis option and I can pursue my CPT and OPT. I don't know whom to pursue or call in the college regarding this. Hence I came here.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, in almost all cases, a PhD student can transfer to a Masters program.  The person to contact is your department head, or dean.  This is surprisingly common, and I've personally know several people who went on to very happy careers after switching to an MS.